# Generating a PVK for creating Offset in HSM

Tags: hsm

I am pretty new to HSM. Currently I need to integrate a HSM to my application for storing the PINs in secured fashion. To do this I have to use the command DE to create offset of the encrypted PIN, but this will require a PVK as input. I need to know the steps to create the PVK. (Commands and Steps).

I tried the following steps

```
FK
Key length [1,2,3]: 2
Key Type: 002
Key Scheme: U
Component type [X,H,E,S]: X
Enter number of components (2-9): 2
Enter component #1: **12345678901234567890123456789021**
Enter component #2: **12345678901234567890123456789012**
Encrypted key: U AB33 69A7 4368 D7DB EE8B 789B 8285 F9ED 
Key check value: 4D35 AA
```

Can anyone tell the above step is the correct way to create a PVK. Also I have entered random numbers as component 1 & 2, is this correct of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

According to result you succeeded to create a Double Length PVK key but I can not generate your key. I think you changed the xor values.
Your sample :

```
12345678901234567890123456789021 XOR 12345678901234567890123456789012 
Result Clear Key must be : 00000000000000000000000000000033
```

and its KCV values: 36D361

**but** your KCV value is : 4D35AA

You result KCV and your calculated KCV must be same.You can check your generated key with using this formula.